# Is it possible to update icon in App Google Play dynamically?

Tags: android, icons, google-play

I am developing a magazine application in Android. For that, I would like to update the icon in google play dynamically with the cover page of my latest magazine (Similar to Newsstand Atom feed in iTunes/iOS)

I would like to know if there is any way to achieve this in Google Play Store?

**P.S : Not Application icon in device.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Google does not provide any APIs for managing Play Store listings, nor does it currently offer a system for automatically updating Play Store app data.